# How can i get the column name and alias in a SOQL query using C#?

Tags: c#, soql

I have a query

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(id) Total
FROM Case
GROUP BY Status
```

The column names are Status and Total. But can i get the before from part, so i get `Status, COUNT(id) Total` so i know what column is associated with an aggregate function.

I have tried the following :

```
   private List<string> GetColumns(string query)
    {
        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
        string pattern = @"(\w*\.*\w+|`\w*.*\w`|(\[)\w*.*(\]))+(,|\s+,|\s+FROM|\s+from)";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(query, pattern))
        {
            string name = m.Groups[1].Value;
            columns.Add(name);
        }

        return columns;
    }
```

But this returns the name `Status` and `Total` not `Status, COUNT(id) Total`.

How can i do this in C# ?

Comment: Why? Do you really need to write your own sql parser? Or can you ask your database engine to work out those names for you?

Comment: thanks I will look into using database engine